# hex2bin is equal password_hash with PASSWORD_DEFAULT algorithm in PHP?

Tags: php

hex2bin is equal password_hash with PASSWORD_DEFAULT algorithm in PHP?
This expression is equal?

```
$token = random_bytes(32)
$sel = hex2bin($token)
$password = password_hash($token,PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
```

And this is true?
`password_verity($sel,$password)`;

How it works?
I think password_hash is the same with bin2hex?
Right?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask. It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.

Comment: I am unsure why they would be the same? `hex2bin`  decodes a hexadecimally encoded binary string and `password_hash` hashes a password?

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.

[password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) uses cryptographically secure hashing algorithms to generate hashes that contain the information necessary to verify them. Converting a string to a different format does none of that.

```php
$token = random_bytes(32);
$sel = hex2bin($token);
```

This will not work, and will generate a warning. [random_bytes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php) does not output hexadecimal strings. Did you mean [bin2hex](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php)? That would result in something like `afc2646f14f875dc2786e7f4579da68dbc154ea65ee98cbe69847e3f50544b28`

```php
$password = password_hash($token,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

`$password` will be something like `$2y$10$Updk7lsecqDhwW4tXZ9lZ.XCEJlEGgWtizqe.O3gQqwCKQhnKgUXO`. [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) uses the [bcrypt hashing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) when using the `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` option. This is nothing like [hex2bin](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php) or [bin2hex](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php).

You should really read and understand the documentation for [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) before implementing an authentication solution, it's easy to do it wrong if you try to hack something together yourself. It looks like you may have copied this code out of an old tutorial on password hashing that predates the `password_hash` and `password_verify` functions. `password_hash` and `password_verify` make it very easy to do passwords right, and unless you *really* know what you are doing, you should just use them.

```php
$password = 'MySuperSecretPassword';

$hash = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$verified = password_verify($password, $hash);

assert($verified, 'Password should be verified against hash created from it');
```